# regex- catch multiple entries between parentheses with overlaps

Tags: regex, sed, awk, grep

I have a string like

```
.....((((...)))...((((..))))....
```

and I want to have 
`.....((((...)))...` and `...((((..))))....`separately..

I came up with `/[.(]*(.?)[.)]*/` which outputs

`.....((((...)))...` and `((((...)))...`

Note that I want to have that three dots lying on the right end in the first cut to be present in the left part of the second cut as well.

Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat file
.....((((...)))...((((..))))....

$ sed -r 's/([^)]+[)]+([^(]+))/\1 \2/' file
.....((((...)))... ...((((..))))....
```

or if your sed doesn't support EREs (-r option) then you can do:

```
$ sed 's/\([^)]*[)]*\([^(]*\)\)/\1 \2/' file
.....((((...)))... ...((((..))))....
```

the semantics are a little different (* = zero or more while + = 1 or more) but it seems OK with your example.

Edit: explanation as requested:

```
sed -r ' # use sed with Extended Regular Expressions enabled so "+" works.
s/       # search command and search start delimiter
(        # start of 1st saved RE-matching string (\1 later) which will contain:
[^)]+    #    1 or more non-) characters (e.g. "."s) then
[)]+     #    1 or more )s then
(        #    start of 2nd saved RE-matching string (\2 later) which will contain:
[^(]+    #        1 or more non-) characters (e.g. "."s)
)        #    end of 2nd saved RE-matching string so by this point \2 = "..."
)        # end of 1st saved RE-matching string so by this point \1 = ".....((((...)))..."
/        # search end delimiter and replacement start delimiter
\1 \2    # print \1=".....((((...)))..." then a space then \2="..." then the remaining unmatched input text="((((..))))...."
/        # replacement end delimiter
' file   # operate on the contents of file "file"
```

Comment: Thank you Ed, many times! If you would care to provide an explanation, I would be thrilled and might save some future question, from being asked.

Comment: @teutara - explanation added.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to do it in 3 steps. The reason is you the middle "..." to be common in both outputs and I doubt its possible in a single regex command. Note: I'm using ".(.)." to refer to your specific string output pattern.

Step 1: Match for ".(.)." and return the first output.
Step 2: Match for the first ".(.)" and remove it from the string.
Step 3: Match the remaining string from Step 2 for ".(.)." and return its output.

I played with it on rubular.com and the regex I got is different from yours.
/(.*(+.*)+.*)(.*(+.*)+.*)/ which is not what you want
/(.*(+.*)+.*)/ this will match an individual ".(.)."

Comment: thanks for pointing out rubular.com and your interest, but I do not think this solution meets the expectation..

Comment: I agree this solution is not the single-line regex expression solution you're looking for but it is an alternative solution that I know will work.  Consider that what you're trying to do may not be possible if regex is designed in a way that doesn't allow same characters to be shared to multiple outputs in a single match. I don't know the inner workings of regex to say for certain but it won't surprise me, if its true.

Answer (score 0):

HM1 is right, you can't match twice some chars in a RE.
An idea is to separatly match the common part and concat after.
An example with gawk:

```
echo "begin(first round bracket)middle(second round bracket)end" | gawk 'match($0, /^([^)]+\))([^(]+)(.+)$/, a) { first=a[1] a[2]; second=a[2] a[3]; print first "\n" second }'
```

Comment: you don't need to match the chars twice, you just need to match them once and then print them twice. I'm curious - what do you think the "++"s in your RE do?

Comment: @EdMorton: I don't have matched the chars twice in my example and I have printed them twice.

Comment: @EdMorton: "++" are possessives quantifiers that avoid the regex engine to backtrack (you say him:"hey, the Re engine, you don't have to backtrack"). this increase the performance, but you can do the same with a simple +. More info here : [link]http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html

Comment: When I mentioned not needing to match twice I was addressing your leading text "you can't match twice some chars in a RE" not your code. Possessive quantifiers aren't supported by any awk AFAIK, certainly not by GNU awk, so I'm not sure what effect they will have in your script.

Comment: O.o sorry, I haven't understand! You're right, GNU awk doesn't support possessive quantifiers. I suppose that gawk interprete that like (.+)+. I will remove them.